# Not able to send updated response from callback function in AWS Lambda to API Gateway

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I have created an API Gateway which routes to AWS Lambda function (Node 8.10). The Lambda function makes POST request to a third party API and should return the response (status and message) back to API GATEWAY. What is happening is that I am able to successfully call third party API (its a post request so I can check that Lambda is doing its job) but when I send response back to API GATEWAY, it is not able to send the updated response.

The reason for this is that Lambda is calling callback(null, response) almost immediately , whereas response from third party API comes later and hence response object is updated later (I can confirm that through console logs). I have written one callback(null, response) inside the callback function as can be seen from attached code snippet but it seems API GATEWAY considers the earliest callback response. How can I make sure that LAMBDA function sends the updated response only. Following is the attached code:

```
const https = require('https');

exports.handler = async (event, context, callback) => {

  var body = JSON.parse(event.body);
  var postData = JSON.stringify(body);
  const options = {
      method: 'POST',
      hostname: app_url
      path: path_value
      port: 443,
      headers: {
          'accept': 'application/json',
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          'Content-Length': postData.length,
          'Authorization': auth_token_value
      }
  };

  var response = {};
  var dataStr = "";

  const req = https.request(options, (res) => {
      response.statusCode = res.statusCode;
      response.headers = res.headers;

      res.on('data', (d) => {
          dataStr += d;
      });

      res.on('end', () => {
          response.body = dataStr;
          console.log(response);
          callback(null, response);
      });
  });

  req.write(postData);
  req.end();

  console.log(response);
  callback(null, response);
}
```

Comment: Remove `req.write(postData)` and `req.end()`. I'm just guessing as, these are not required in lambda. This is not normal nodeJs server. This is `serverless`.

Comment: I have realised that `req.end()` can be removed though it does not solve the issue - it was a redundant line. I would need `req.write(postData)` otherwise I would not be able to post the payload. @NAVIN

Answer (score 1):

The final working code is below. I still have to figure our on `res.headers` part though.

```
const https = require('https');

exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {

    var body = JSON.parse(event.body);
    var postData = JSON.stringify(body);
    const options = {
        method: 'POST',
        hostname: app_url,
        path: path_value,
        port: 443,
        headers: {
            'accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Content-Length': postData.length,
            'Authorization': auth_token_value
        }
    };

    var response = {};
    var dataStr = "";

    const req = https.request(options, (res) => {
        response.statusCode = res.statusCode;
        response.headers = {}; // TODO: should be res.headers ideally

        res.on('data', (d) => {
            dataStr += d;
        });

        res.on('end', () => {
            response.body = dataStr;
            console.log(response);
            callback(null, response);
        });
    });

    req.write(postData);
    req.end();
}
```

Comment: Changes done from initial code are:

1. remove async (it was making lambda not wait for final value)

2. remove final callback line (it was sending empty response before call was finished)

3. hard code res.headers to {}. original value was somehow corrupting the response -  may be it was not getting converted into proper hash which is the expectation.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to remove the last two lines (`console.log` and the call to the `callback` function), otherwise they are going to be called synchronously, before the response to your request arrives to you.

Comment: Please first see and read about AWS lambda. `callback` functions are the one which send response back not `res.send` or other functions. last two lines are what makes AWS lambda works. I'm not down voting, But its a wrong answer.

Comment: yep. NAVIN is correct. If I remove last two lines, I get `Execution failed due to configuration error: Malformed Lambda proxy response. Method completed with status: 502`. Which means that somehow API GATEWAY believes that Lambda did not return the response in proper format (statusCode, body, headers).

Comment: Hey @NAVIN, you're right, but the callback function is being called in the `res.on('end'...` block, which executes when the response arrives. Am I missing something? Since @Vikram3891 is getting that 502 error, it may be that the response never comes from the web server and that's where the problem is.

Comment: `res.on('end'....` or `res`  function only exist in `https.request`. It's a callback function for `https` not for lambda handler. lambda handler have it's own 2 input fields, `event`, `content`, and `callback` like in normal `express` framework `req`, `res` and `next`.

Comment: the callback written inside `res.on("end"...` does get executed but it is null and void because the callback written in last line is already executed and API GATEWAY has already responded for the given API. callback function written after `req.end()` is called immediately and hence responds with empty response object. I am just thinking if somehow I could make the callback in last line wait till response object is populated.

Comment: Waiting for the response is done using the "end" event. That event executes after the response and it's complete payload has been transferred from the web server. So the right place to call the callback function is the event handler function for the "end" event. But use a tool like Fiddler or Postman to test and make sure that the web server is really responding correctly to that request - this might as well be where your problem is.

Comment: I have been testing at all three places - Postman, API GATEWAY and Lambda. Lambda is working fine if I just run the Lambda function. But when I test with postman or API GATEWAY, I either start getting empty response (with 200 status code which is default) or malformed error (When I remove last line of callback)

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: was given by AdrianT. Remove the last two lines.

Long answer: When you call http.request (in req.end()) the function call is made in asynchronous mode. This means that everything that the function receives as parameters, will be executed in some point in the future.

But just after a asynchronous call (fire and *forget*), the function continues the execution in the next line. In your exemple the next line is console.log and then callback(null, response). Probably this two lines are executed long time (in cpu time) before the network trip make the first part of the path to the third party server.

With the callback the event source of lambda is informed of the result of the lambda invocation. Even if the function continues his execution (waiting for the still open events in the event loop), the function return was already sent. So the event source, in this case API Gateway understand that the function already did his job and forward it to the caller.

Comment: Agree with the flow that you have mentioned. The reason because of which I am forced to add `callback...` in the last line is due to some weird behavior (so far for me) from Lambda-API GATEWAY duo. If I remove this line, they start complaining with `Execution failed due to configuration error: Malformed Lambda proxy response. Method completed with status: 502`. It seems they do not wait till `res.on("end"...` is executed. But as a collateral damage of adding callback line, lambda is sending empty response object since it is not yet populated.

Comment: Two things for you to investigate: First check the format of response.body. It must be an object and maybe the third party api is using some invalid type that does not parse to an Json object. Second: check the lambda execution timeout parameter. Maybe the function is signaling a timeout before you get a chance to receive the response from third party api.

Comment: Also, check the format of response.statusCode for the same reasons explained above.

Comment: If I remove the last line, I get the error. it does not even wait till `res.on("end"...` (there are no logs in cloud watch). If I let last line be there, then API GETWAY gets blank response object (again confirmed from cloud watch and from API GATEWAY) though `res.on("end"...` prints the populated response which is in perfect shape - but then its too late by the time response object gets populated. I tried to put in wait before final callback, but somehow it caused the timeout from lambda. Moreover I cannot rely on wait, since it will add a definitive slowness in API.

Comment: I tried to use another npm module called `requestify` but it started giving me another issue of `CSRF` - not sure why CSRF was not there with https module. it seems requestify is more like browser (I may be wrong).

Comment: I'm looking again and find something in your code that I didn't understood: why you are defining the lambda handler as async function? As I understand, that function must not be async. It could be a sync function to process the event and only the https.request inside it would be async (already is, because of https module).

I think you are overcomplicating the node.js event loop and this could be the problem.

Comment: yep. you are right. I had to make three changes in order to get it run. I shared below the final working code. Though I am still missing on headers part.If I send res.headers, it starts complaining.

Comment: Check to format of response.headers and check the expected response format in API Gateway. I believe that you must send an JSON in response.headers (double check it. I do not know direct from memory). Your res.headers probably will be a escaped string.

Answer (score 0):

Since the whole chaos was due to asynchronous nature of node script and I did not have any advantage due to asynchronous way of doing stuffs here in my small lambda function, I ended up writing the same code in Python (using `requests` module). Now it's all working fine. But I would still be interested in knowing how can I solve my problem using node script here.